# Worklight JSON store encryption of collection not working in ios

Tags: ios, json, encryption, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using JSONStore in my application to store some sensitive data. To encrypt collection,we are passing options with username and password as mentioned below. In android so far its working fine but in ios devices we are getting blank page while retrieving data from collection (working fine in simulators). I'm not getting any errors also.Without passing options in ios, its working fine. Has anybody faced similar issue?

```
factory('todoJsonStorage',['$q', function ($q) {
'use strict';

var COLLECTION_NAME = 'Users';
var collections = {
        Users: {
            searchFields: {UserId: 'string', password: 'string'}
        },
    };
var options = {};

//Optional username
options.username = 'testuser';
//Optional password
options.password = 'test123';

 //Optional local key generation flag
 options.localKeyGen = true;

var inited = false;

//checks if inited and if not inits
function initJSONStore(){
    var initDeferred = $q.defer();
    if (inited){
        initDeferred.resolve();
    } else {
        //Initialize the collection
        WL.JSONStore.init(collections,options).then(function () {
            console.log("-> JSONStore init successful");
            initDeferred.resolve();
        }).fail(function (errorObject) {
            console.log("-> JSONStore error: " + errorObject.msg);
        });

        return initDeferred.promise;
    };
}

return {
    get: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        initJSONStore().then(function(){
            WL.JSONStore.get(COLLECTION_NAME).findAll().then(function (res) {
                if (res.length > 0){
                    deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(res[0].json.data || '[]'));
                } else {
                      deferred.resolve(res);                   
                      }

            }).fail(function (errorObject) {
                console.log("JSONStore findbyid error: " + errorObject.msg);
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },

    put: function (todos) {
        WL.JSONStore.get(COLLECTION_NAME).clear();
        WL.JSONStore.get(COLLECTION_NAME).add({data:JSON.stringify(todos)});
    }
};

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 10, you must enable the Keychain Sharing Capability, otherwise this should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks Adar. But we tested ios version less than 10 only even i m getting blank page while retrieving json store.

Comment: Hi Idan, we are using   IBM 7.1.0.00-20151023-1441 version, while passing password option in ios, we are getting the below error , get method called (console-via-logger.js, line 175)

[Log] get method called (console-via-logger.js, line 175)

[Log] -> JSONStore init successful (console-via-logger.js, line 175)

[Log] -> JSONStore error: PROVISION_TABLE_SEARCH_FIELDS_MISMATCH (console-via-logger.js, line 175)

[Log] JSONStore findbyid error: PERSISTENT_STORE_NOT_OPEN (console-via-logger.js, line 175)

Please help

Comment: Please feel free to open a PMR so that O Support could help you.